# Creating a Freemium plugin in the WordPress Repository

Tags: plugins

I would like to create a freemium model plugin and put it in the WordPress repository.

I've been going through the rules for uploading plugins into the repository, but haven't got a clear indication on whether this is allowed or not, so I am searching for clarification here.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/guidelines/

I also came across WYSIJA which is a freemium plugin, and it is hosted in the repository without any problems, so I'm assuming it's ok to do this, however I would like some definitive reply on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define "freemium".

If you mean a free plugin that attempts to up-sell to a paid-for plugin, sure, that's allowed. As long as you do it within the guidelines you've already found.

If you ask a more specific question, you'll get a more specific answer. What do you want the plugin to do that you think may not be allowed?

Comment: I meant what you said, I was confused because this thread here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-rules-and-freemium?replies=7 seemed to imply that this is not allowed.

Comment: In that thread, he's talking about creating features in the plugin itself and then requiring payment to "turn them on". That we don't allow, everything in the plugin has to be enabled. However, if you left the extra features out, and sold a different plugin from your own site with those features (sort of like a "Plugin Pro Edition" or something), then that's okay.

Comment: I believe WYSIJA http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wysija-newsletters/ has all the features in the plugin itself, which is why my doubt arose. I was about to follow that model for my own plugin, so I asked to confirm.

Comment: That sort of thing is expressly NOT allowed, and I have emailed them about it.